# hive prompt is not loading using the hive command

Tags: hadoop, hive

I installed hive successfully. Then i tried to launch the hiveserver2 thrift. then something went wrong and now the hive prompt also not getting loaded.

```
 Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.2.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
```

the execution is stuck at this message. Can anyone help me to fix this.

Comment: can you have start metastore??

Comment: I have derby installed. And its working fine...
OS name:         Linux
OS architecture: amd64
OS version:      4.10.0-28-generic
Java user name:  ecsch1l12
Java user home:  /home/ecsch1l12
Java user dir:   /usr/local/hadoop
java.specification.name: Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.version: 1.8
java.runtime.version: 1.8.0_151-b12
--------- Derby Information --------
[/usr/local/hadoop/hive/lib/derby-10.10.2.0.jar] 10.10.2.0 - (1582446)
[/usr/local/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-1.2.2-standalone.jar] 10.10.2.0 - (1582446)